# Windows 7 sound control is not flexible. 

Tags: windows-7, audio

I would like to be able to listen to music on both of two audio output devices, but Windows 7 seems to only allow me to select one or the other as the Default device.  When device A is the Default device, device B is muted; and vice versa.  This seems to be stunningly inflexible.

Since Windows 7 is unable to do this, can anyone recommend any add-on software that would control the hardware more flexibly and thoughtfully?

Comment: "Win7 seems to only allow me to select one or the other as the Default device."  Yeah stupid Windows! Letting you only pick ONE "Default Device". :P

Comment: I’m pretty sure that the restriction applies only to the *default* device. I’m fairly certain that you can have a program select what audio device to use. For example, open two instances of a media player that lets you select the output device and set each to a different one. Play something in each player and it *should* output to each device independently.

Comment: @techie007, lol; though to be fair, the video cards can be configured to simultaneously output the same thing to more than one display. Of course that is a vendor-specific setting, hence Thahaseena’s suggestion to contact the audio-card’s mfg.

Comment: @Synetech inc. Yeah, I was just bugging him (post edit :) ).

Comment: I suppose a better way of putting it, techie007, would be that it is too bad that Win7 only allows one to direct audio output to one device at a time, and that is by declaring the device to be the default device.  There are mixers build into the software: why not have a matrix of inputs and outputs, with volume controls for each node?  Oh, well.  Microsoft has only been doing this for 20 years.  They haven't really had much time to try to develop a full-featured product.

Answer (score 1):

I found this from Microsoft:

```
Multiple audio output is not supported by windows 7. It is by design. 
However you can contact the hardware manufacturer for other possibilities.

Thank you and Regards.           

Thahaseena M
Microsoft Answers Support Engineer.
```

But with that said I also found this solution:

[Virtual Audio Cable](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Virtual-Audio-Cable-Download-2217.html)

[More Info On Virtual Audio Cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Audio_Cable)

Here are instructions for doing this:

```
How to do it:
1) Create one virtual audio cable. Is already created after install, 
it is called "Virtual Cable 1". You don't have to modify anything.
2) Run "Audio Repeater (KS)" from Start menu.
3) In the Wave In combo select "Virtual Cable 1".
4) In the Wave Out combo select "Audio Speaker" (depends on computer).
5) Click Start
6) Run SECOND "Audio Repeater (KS) from Start menu.
7) In the Wave In combo select "Virtual Cable 1".
8) In the Wave Out combo select "Audio SPDIF Out" (depends on computer).
9) Click Start
10) Run Windows Media Player, go to menu Tools, Options, Devices, 
    double click Speakers, select Virtual Audio Cable, click OK 2x.
11) Play audio in the player
12) Enjoy never before possible multiple output audio playback!
13) And yes I fully agree that Microsoft developers are a bunch of morons!
```

I have not done this and unsure how well it works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hope it can help =>

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the application and drivers. It is totally possible as I can have a youtube video playing through my front Inputs, but have Windows Media Player playing though my back inputs.

This is on an Asus M479XTD EVO motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way that I use which I found a few years ago that outputs the same audio on all devices at the same time.

http://neosmart.net/downloads/guides/Vista_Sound/rtkhdaud.zip

Just extract to Windows/System32/Drivers for output to SPDIF and ANALOGUE

Comment: When you recommend software, please post a link to the a descriptive page. People need to read about the program and decide for themselves whether it meets their specific needs. Directly linking the download is not very helpful.